# Node: serving secure (wss://) and insecure (ws://) connections with the same server

Tags: node.js, web-services, websocket

I have a Node server which is using the [ws](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws) websocket library. I need to serve both `ws` and `wss` connections, since not all of my clients can communicate with `wss`. Is it possible for a single websocket server to serve both type of connections? If so, how?

Currently I initialize my server like this:

```
var https = require('https');
var WebSocketServer   = ws.Server;
var fs = require('fs');
var app = https.createServer({
        key: fs.readFileSync( ssl_key ),
        cert: fs.readFileSync( ssl_cert )
    }, processRequest ).listen( port );

var wss = new WebSocketServer( { server: app } );
```

This however prevents insecure `ws` connections (handshakes fail). Is it possible to have both type of connections served?

Thank you for suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so it turned out to be quite simple. The idea is to use a proxy, which can take care of both types of connections. The original server does not need to be modified, which is nice. I ended up using the [http-proxy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-proxy) package (naturally, more approaches are [available](https://github.com/observing/balancerbattle)). The relevant code looks like this:

```
require('http-proxy').createProxyServer({
    target: {
        host: 'localhost', // the insecure (ws://) websocket server
        port: 9000, 
        ws: true
    },
    secure: true,
    ssl: {
        key: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/server.key'),
        cert: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/server.crt')
    }
}).listen(8000);
```